# Series of $-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{1+k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find the exact value of the power series $-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{1+k^2}$

It looks like it could have something to do with $\arctan x$ or some sort of trigonometric function, but I don't have a clue where to start.

It would be great if there are any hints on how to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: Consider the function $$f(z) = \frac{\pi}{\left(1+z^2\right)\sin(\pi z)}$$ The contour integral along a circle of radius $R$ tends to zero if $R$ is sent to infinity. If you express the contour integral as the sum of all the residues at the poles inside the contour, then you get your summation (also over negative $k$ but summand is even), and there are two poles at $z = \pm i$. So, the summation can be expressed in terms of the residues at $z = \pm i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding Complex Analysis, a simple way is to notice that the given series is absolutely convergent and it is related to the Fourier (cosine) series of $e^{-|x|}$ over $(-\pi,\pi)$. Indeed 
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-|x|}\,dx = \frac{1-e^{-\pi}}{\pi},\qquad \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-|x|}\cos(nx)\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi(n^2+1)}\left(1-(-1)^n e^{-\pi}\right) $$
imply
$$ e^{-|x|}\stackrel{L^2}{=}\frac{1-e^{-\pi}}{\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)(1-(-1)^n e^{-\pi})}{n^2+1} $$
but we also have pointwise convergence over $[-\pi,\pi]$ due to the summability of $\frac{1}{n^2+1}$. In particular we are allowed to just evaluate both sides at $x=\pi$ and $x=0$ to get:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{\pi}{\sinh \pi}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
-\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 1 + k^{2}} & =
\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k + \ic} =
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + 1 + \ic/2} -
{1 \over k + 1/2 + \ic/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\bracks{\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic} -
\Psi\pars{1 + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}}\qquad\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\end{align}

> [See $\color{#000}{\mathbf{6.3.12}}$ and $\color{#000}{\mathbf{6.3.13}}$, respectively, in A&S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm):
>   
>   $\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{\Im\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}} & \ds{=} &
> \ds{\phantom{-}{1 \over 2}\,\pi\tanh\pars{\pi \over 2}}
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\Im\Psi\pars{1 + {1 \over 2}\,\ic}} & \ds{=} &
> \ds{-1 + {1 \over 2}\,\pi\coth\pars{\pi \over 2}}
> \end{array}\right.$

such that
$$
\bbx{-\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 1 + k^{2}} =
{1 \over 2}\bracks{1 - \pi\,\mrm{csch}\pars{\pi}} \approx 0.3640}
$$